# Execution order of coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I run Code A and get Result A, run Code B and get Result B,

I think Result B should be Result B+ because `b.await()` is called, why was the execution not as expected?

**Code A**

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
    val a = async {    
        //delay(200L) 
        println("A1")        
    }    

    val b = async {    
        //delay(100L) 
        println("A2")        
    } 


    //b.await()

    println("A3")
}
```

**Result A**

```
A3
A1
A2
```

**Code B**

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
    val a = async {    
        //delay(200L) 
        println("A1")        
    }    

    val b = async {    
        //delay(100L) 
        println("A2")        
    } 


    b.await()

    println("A3")
}
```

**Result B**

```
A1
A2
A3
```

**Result B+**

```
A2
A3
A1
```

**Added Content**

BTW, the Code C get the Result B+

**Code C**

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
    val a = async {    
        delay(200L) 
        println("A1")        
    }    

    val b = async {    
        delay(100L) 
        println("A2")        
    } 


    b.await()

    println("A3")
}
```

Comment: With each coroutine doing nothing but a `print` the order is probably highly dependent on the details of the coroutines scheduling code. If you add the `delay` in the `A1` coroutine that you have commented out, the order is Result B+ as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the placement order in the code also affects invokes. Because even this code:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val a = async {
        delay(200L)
        println("A1")
    }

    val b = async {
        delay(200L)
        println("A2")
    }

    b.await()
    a.await()
    println("A3")

}
```

will output:

```
A1
A2
A3
```

For output A2, A3, A1, you can use:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val a = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        //delay(200L)
        println("A1")
    }

    val b = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        //delay(200L)
        println("A2")
    }

    b.await()
    println("A3")
    a.await()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW Right, yes it works! It turns out that the delay value also affects the order.

Answer (score 1):

Let me dissect the code line by line,

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
  val a=async {    
     //delay(200L) 
     println("A1")        
  }    

  val b= async {    
      //delay(100L) 
      println("A2")        
  } 


  b.await()

  println("A3")
}
```

When the control execution starts from the main method it works as follows,

1.`runBlocking` : As soon as `runBlocking` was encountered, the main thread was blocked until and unless the `runBlocking` coroutine completed. The `runBlocking` holds a `CoroutineScope` and no scope ever ends until and unless the children inside the scope complete i.e `runBlocking` will only complete when all the children coroutines inside completes first.

2. `val a = async{}`: When async is encountered it immediately returns a Deferred value and no code inside async is executed. Although it is never mentioned in docs but it feels as if compiler internally maintains a queue like mechanism where it stores the encountered coroutines position-wise i.e coroutine encountered first will be the first to get dispatched. So in this way, this `async{}` is stored in such queue and will be the prime candidate to get dispatched when the currently running coroutine(`runBlocking{}`) is suspended.
3. `val b = async{}`: Same goes with this `async{}` block, the compiler won't execute the code inside this `async` but will store this coroutine in the same mysterious queue at the second position.
4. `b.await()`: As soon as `b.await()` is called, the currently running coroutine `runBlocking{}` is suspended and then dispatcher picks the topmost element in the internal queue i.e in our case `val a = async{}` and handles it to the main thread for execution as a result you saw `A1` getting printed and not `A2`.
5. When the `val a = async{}` coroutine is completed, the dispatcher picked the second element in the queue which this time was `val b= async {}` and handled it to the main thread as a result you saw `A2`.
6. Once `val b= async {}` was over the job of `b.await()` i.e to return the result of Deferred operation was over too, no elements were present in the queue, hence the parent coroutine `runBlocking{}` resumed the execution and finally printed the output `A3`.
7. Since all the internal child coroutine had executed, the `runBlocking{}` was allowed to complete. As soon as `runBlocking{}` was complete, no work was left for the main thread to execute and hence the program ended.

**TL DR; The position of the `coroutines` declaration holds importance.**